# Size of file was 10MB, after reboot it 0 Bytes

Tags: files

I have file `.blend`. Yesterday it was about 10MB. Now it is just 0 Byte. How can i restore it. Ubuntu define this file as `empty file`

Comment: If it's 0 bytes, it would be defined as an "empty file"; a text file contains text characters so can't be 0 bytes.  You also should not use \* in a filename so I suspect your issue relates to your filename itself.

Comment: Just restore it from your daily / weekly / monthly backup ... ;-)

Comment: No)) My filename is not `*.blend` ))

Comment: I didnt do backup. Or ubuntu automatically do backup?

Comment: 1) Backup is not automatic until you set up automatic backup. The programs to fdo it are in Ubuntu, but you must tell the system what you want backed up, how often, and to where. 2) Which app did you use to make the file you're asking about? 3) Your question says "_I have file .blend. _"  Please go into a terminal and run `ls -l` in the directory where that file is, copy the result and paste it into your question after clicking [edit]; please also answer question 2. Please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: 2) Blender 2.8.